# pass $(this) in JQuery on event for deleting a row in a table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following html code which represents a part of a table

```
<tr>
   <td>    
      <span class='tip'><a href='#' class='Delete' data-name='product1' title='Delete'><img src='images/icon/icon_delete.png'></a></span>"
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>    
      <span class='tip'><a href='#' class='Delete' data-name='product2' title='Delete'><img src='images/icon/icon_delete.png'></a></span>"
   </td>
</tr>
```

and some JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.Delete', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    $.confirm({
        'title': 'DELETE ROW',
        'message': "<strong>DO YOU WANT TO DELETE </strong><br /><font color=red>' " + name + " ' </font> ",
        'buttons': {
            'Yes': {
                'class': 'special',
                'action': function () {

                    // this is the problem
                    // i am trying to get the row
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);

                    oTable.fnDeleteRow(row);

                }
            },
            'No': { 'class': '' }
        }
    });
});
```

I am trying to get the row id so i will be able to delete it.
how can i pass the caller to the `click` event

**EDIT:** i am trying to delete a row, maybe there are other ways

Comment: there is no id for the table

Comment: Use another `data` attribute for `id` as you have for `name`

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to get the *row Index*?

Comment: i cant see any id for the row in the html markup you provided

Comment: where should i add the id? in every td? can you show code example

Comment: Like this:
<td>    
      <span class='tip'><a href='#' class='Delete' data-id='12' title='Delete'><img src='images/icon/icon_delete.png'></a></span>"
   </td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that inside the $.confirm plugin's `action` callback function, the value of `this` is likely something else (i.e. not the DOM node). save a reference to `$(this)` before calling the plugin, and use that reference inside the `action` callback. something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Delete', function () {
    var node = $(this);
    var name = node.attr("data-name");
    $.confirm({
        'title': 'DELETE ROW',
        'message': "<strong>DO YOU WANT TO DELETE </strong><br /><font color=red>' " + name + " ' </font> ",
        'buttons': {
            'Yes': {
                'class': 'special',
                'action': function () {
                    var row = node.closest("tr").get(0);
                    oTable.fnDeleteRow(row);
                }
            },
            'No': { 'class': '' }
        }
    });
});
```

This is a bit of guess, since I'm not farmilar with your confirm plugin, but it's a common JS pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();` should get rid of it.

Comment: i am getting undefined when i do var test = $(this).parent().parent().parent()